# Can I create several different insert queries under one connection string to Mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql

After opening connection string to mysql database, can I create several different insert queries?
(I must to separate them since the first query is in a loop).
If so, I would like to know the format.

Example:

```
string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=123";

string Query1 = "insert into table1 (value1) values('" + value1+ "');";

string Query2 = "insert into table2 (value2) values('" + value2+ "');";
```

Comment: dont concat SQL use Parameters https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always run two queries using the same string.

```
string Query1 = "insert into table1 (value) values('" + value+ "');";

string Query2 = "insert into table1 (value2) values('" + value2+ "');";

string Query = Query1 + Query2;

run(Query) // <--I forgot the actual command, but that's the logic.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can insert multiple values by separating them with commas, like so:

`string query = "INSERT INTO table1 (value, value2) VALUES ('" + value + "', '" + value2 + "');";`

You can also insert multiple rows by separating your values with commas, like so:

`string query = "INSERT INTO table1 (value) VALUES ('" + value1 + "'), ('" + value2 + "');";`